Why does $\lim_{x\to 0^+} \sqrt{x^2-x}$ exist?
I'm studying the function $f(x) = \sqrt{x^2-x}$ and it's domain is $D = (-\infty, 0] \cup [1, +\infty)$.
I don't understand why $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = 0$.
Indeed I do agree that $\lim_{x\to 0^-} \sqrt{x^2-x} \to 0$ but why does $\lim_{x\to 0^+} \sqrt{x^2-x}$ exist at all?
The function is not defined for $0<x<1$.
On the other side I recognize that the domain includes the point $x = 0$. This is not clear to me, because if I take $x = 0 + \epsilon$, for $0 < \epsilon < 1$, I get
$$f(0 + \epsilon) = \sqrt{\epsilon^2 - \epsilon} = \sqrt{\epsilon(\epsilon - 1)}$$ and since $0 < \epsilon < 1$, the product in the square root is negative, hence the square root shouldn't have limit at $x \to 0^+$.
Sorry if this is (another) stupid question, I cannot reconcile this fact with the fact that it's indeed defined at $0$.

You are only supposed to look at $x \to 0$ in the domain of $f$. No need to consider $x \to 0+$.

So the limit at $x\to 0^+$ anyway doesn't exist, does it? Because even W. Mathematica tells me it's zero (on both the directions)

The limit ad $x\to 0^+$ is not defined at all.

Evaluating the limit for $x\to 0^+$ makes no sense because there are no "right" neighborhoods of zero in which you can evaluate $f$. However, in these cases, the continuity requires only to check the lateral limit where $f$ is defined.

@user: Both questions are about the limit at a point if the function is only defined on one side of that point. I think it is clearly explained in the other thread.

@MartinR Yes, looking at the general context, it is fine as duplicate.

@MartinR Ok, but when I have to study the asymptotes or the directional limits, that limit shouldn't exist.

@MartinR Also, for the limit to exist it has to be two-sided, but since $x\to 0^+$ doesn't make sense, then it shouldn't the limit for $x\to 0$ either...

@SigmaAlgebra For the limit to exist it has to be two-sided, but since $x\to 0^+$ doesn't make sense, then it shouldn't the limit for $x\to 0$ either...

@geetha290krm Well if I have to study ALL the limits, then I have to study that too. And it doesn't exist. So how is the limit at $x\to 0$ defined, if the two.sided is not defined?
